# Why no suitable constructor for SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

Here is the error.

[image]

FastRenderView.java

```
package framework.impl;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import framework.Game;

public class FastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Game game;
    Bitmap frameBuffer;
    Thread renderThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    public FastRenderView(Game game, Bitmap frameBuffer) {
        super(game);
        this.game = game;
        this.frameBuffer = frameBuffer;
        this.holder = getHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Rect dstRect = new Rect();
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        while(running) {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            game.getScreen().update(deltaTime);
            game.getScreen().present(deltaTime);

            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect);
            canvas.drawBitmap(frameBuffer, null, dstRect, null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        running = true;
        renderThread = new Thread(this);
        renderThread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        running = false;
        while(true) {
            try {
                renderThread.join();
                break;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // retry
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that on line 19 I get the error that is showed above for 'super(game);'

The question is how do I fix this?

If you need more information then let me know!!!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

When you call super(), you are passing the game object the the parent constructor, which is that of SurfaceView. The only single-parameter constructor implemented by SurfaceView takes a Context Object. Does the Game class inherit from Context somewhere in the inheritance chain?

If no, then there's your problem. If yes, post the code for the Game class.

Comment: Very simple fix, I changed Game on line 18 to AndroidGame so that I would have context available. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! And it turned out to be a much simpler problem than I anticipated, which is great!